# Float array to float *

Tags: ios, c, arrays, pointers

What is the difference between `float[]` and `float*`?

Also, how can I convert a float array to `float *`? I need to get a `float *` and open it, then apply a filter and send it as a `float *` into my FFT method, but I don't know how to do it because I don't know the real difference between them.

Comment: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/

Comment: Exactly the same as in C.  Learn C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These points all relate to C:

- the name of an array can be decomposed — i.e. implicitly converted — to a pointer to its first element;
- in an array, elements are stored contiguously;
- the syntax `a[8]` is just shorthand for `*(a + 8)`; and
- adding `n` to a pointer, `p`, is defined to add `n * sizeof(*p)`.

So an array differs from a pointer by being a semantically different thing. But you can supply the name of an array anywhere a pointer is required as it'll be converted.

Separately, you can also add an offset to any pointer using subscript syntax.

Objective-C is a strict superset of C. So these rules also apply to the use of the primitive types in Objective-C.

---

To understand the distinction, think in terms of mutability. The following is invalid:

```
char array[];
char value;

array = &value;
```

You can't reassign `array`. It is the name of an array. `array` itself is not mutable at runtime, only the things within it are. Conversely the following is valid:

```
char *pointer;
char value;

pointer = &value;
```

You can reassign `pointer` as often as you like. There's a mutable pointer and you can use it to point to anything.

Comment: thanks for the help and great explanation. it really helped to understand the point

Comment: can you help me on my new challange please , deeply appreciated

Answer (score 2):

An array usually is a pointer to the first member of the list. When using Array[Identifier], you are accessing to *(p+Identifier).

Making a new array will define a series of pointer next to another, which will make it's use way easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can set your float array in the following ways:

```
float array1[100] = { 0 }; 
float *dataArray = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * 100);
float *pointerToFloatArray = array1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use C-style arrays, like described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26263070/3399208,

but better way - is using Objective-C containers and Objective-C objects, for example NSNumber * :

```
NSArray *array = [@1, @2, @3];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
NSNumber *number1 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:20.f];
NSNumber *number2 = @(20.f);
[array addObject:number1];
[array addObject:number2];
```